# model not passing to controller from view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to mvc and javascript.At first I am using javascript to appned the parital view in divsion

```
$('.btngo').click(function (e) {
        var fid = $('#FiscalYear_FYId').val();
      alert($('#FiscalYear_FYId').val());
        $.ajax({
            type: 'Get',
            url: '@Url.Action("RateList", "Rate")',
            data: { fyid: fid },
            success: function (sc) {
                $('#Ratelist').html(sc);

            }
        });
    });
```

The  partial view is of model FHIControl.Model.StationeryRate.RateDTO which consists a submit button my view looks like

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Ratelist", "Rate", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Item Id</th>
    <th>Item Name</th>
    <th>Rate</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>

   @Html.HiddenFor(x=>Model.FiscalYear.FYId)
     @foreach (var item in Model.RateList)
      {
        <tr>
             @Html.HiddenFor(x => item.ItemId)
         <td>@{count++;}@count</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.ItemName)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => item.Rate)</td>
        </tr>
      }


</table>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Ok" id="btnsubmit" />
        </p>
}
```

The button submit is submiting the form but there is no model items.Why is it so?Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no model items because you are only passing the value of `FiscalYear_FYId`:

```
    var fid = $('#FiscalYear_FYId').val();
    $.ajax({
        data: { fyid: fid },                    
    });
```

which should be:

```
    $.ajax({
        data: $form.serialize(),            
    });
```

where `$form` is a reference to your form. That you can either give a name for faster and better reference, or you can reference it like this:

```
    var $form = $("#btnsubmit").parents('form');
```